# Python Webcam Http streaming and Image capture

Tags: python, webcam

Using Python, I need to be able to create a http streaming video from the webcam and capture a still image from that http source.
I thought I could use VLC player to stream the video and just capture a frame using python, but If the webcam is being used by VLC, Python cannot use it to grab a still image.
This lead to the thinking that I could use python to stream the video and I could use the same script to take a still image grab when needed. I will use the http stream to display the video using a proprietory software we use, and when the button is clicked, grab a still image.

Any suggestions please on the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Any help, anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the webcam hosting machine is Windows or Linux:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame, sys
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,240))
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video4",(320,240))

cam.start()
while 1:
    image = cam.get_image()
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.set_caption(str("TUX PLOT CAM"))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         sys.exit()
```

I found this snippet here:
(https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-stream-a-webcam-with-python-905968/)

And also, it seems there is a solution for Windows:
http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/

Here is another snippet (also using pygame):
http://www.jperla.com/blog/post/capturing-frames-from-a-webcam-on-linux